# How do I set the correct type for a click handler when using Svelte with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, eventhandler

I am using Svelte with TypeScript. I have a button:

```
<button on:click|preventDefault={clickHandler}>
   Click me
</button>
```

I am trying to set the correct type for the click handler.

```
export let clickHandler: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

I got `MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>` from the TS error when I use a different type, eg:

> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.

However this fails with `Cannot find name 'MouseEventHandler'`. I can't work out where to import the type `MouseEventHandler` as it's not exported by Svelte.

**How do I set the correct type for a click handler when using Svelte with TypeScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating further, Svelte's Event handlers - yes Svelte's not React's - are under `svelte.JSX`. Yes, when you're using normal `.svelte` components and not using JSX. I did see `JSX` references in my research but ignored them because I was not using JSX. But I guess maybe Svelte's TS functionality leverages some existing work from React?

[image]

So the correct TS type for a click handler is:

```js
export let clickHandler: svelte.JSX.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

Comment: The way that the language features work is by transforming the components first. They used to be transformed to TSX, but there has been a rewrite of the transform, so by default that might not be the case anymore. Maybe the namespaces will be changed once the old transform gets removed from the codebase.

Comment: Thanks @H.B. - if the namespace gets changed I'll update the answer to mention.

Answer (score 0):

While you can type the property, you might want to just forward the event instead:

```html
<button on:click|preventDefault>
   Click me
</button>
```

([Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname) - After modifiers)

That way, whatever uses the component can just also add an `on:click` to the component.

Comment: Not really answering what was questioned....
It could have been a comment instead. 
A good one, thought.