# What is the correct way to type svelete on:click and on:keydown events?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have seen on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74069649/how-do-i-set-the-correct-type-for-a-click-handler-when-using-svelte-with-typescr) that the supposed correct type for an `on:click` event in *Svelte* is :

```js
  const handleClick = (e: svelte.JSX.MouseEventHandler<HTMLLIElement>) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  };
```

However this isn't the case:

[image: Svelte screenshot of vsc showing the error]

And if I try to change it to `MouseEventHandler<HTMLLIElement>` the type is not importable.

[image: Svelte screenshot of vsc showing uimportable type]

Answer (score 3):

The type is for the *entire* handler, not the event supplied to it. I.e. you would add the type here:

```js
const handler: svelte.JSX.MouseEventHandler<HTMLLIElement> = e => {
    
}
```

Using a named type is not necessary either, I just usually type the event object and use a type assertion on `target`/`currentTarget` if I need to or you can add the intersection manually, e.g.

```js
function handler(e: MouseEvent) {
  const li = e.currentTarget as HTMLLiElement;
  ...
}

function handler(e: MouseEvent & { currentTarget: HTMLLiElement }) {
  ...
}
```

Also, you seem to add a click handler on a `li` element. You should generally *not* do that, click events belong on buttons for accessibility.